# Model Definitions: Ordering Importo Avoid ImportError

Tags: python, django, models

Having trouble getting all of my imports working correctly. They're calling each other before they're defined.

match.models:

```
from player.models import Player

class Match(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```

player.models:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    #yadda yadda

from match.models import Match
class Skill(models.Model):
    player = ForeignKey(Player)
    match = ForeignKey(Match)
```

That's all candy apples, works fine. But then I wanted to add a model method to **Player**:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    def get_skill():
        skill = Skill.objects.filter()
```

Now, **Skill** is not defined before the player. Moving **Skill** to have it defined before **Player** (and therefore importing match ahead of it) breaks **Match**, because it has to import **Player** which isn't defined yet.

```
File "...match/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from player.models import Player
ImportError: cannot import name Player
```

You get the idea.

I'd really like to keep the model method, I'm just clueless about making all the imports work. I guess I could pull **Skill** out of player.models into its own, but that will be a headache at this point and I'd like to know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Lazy Relationships`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#lazy-relationships)

match models.py

```
class Match(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey('player.Player')
```

player models.py

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    player = ForeignKey('Player')
    match = ForeignKey('match.Match')

class Player(models.Model):
    #yadda yadda

    def get_skill():
       skill = Skill.object.filter()
```

Comment: After going through them all, this worked. I had only tried on the one. Many thanks!